# Why can I only have one Pokemon in the gym battle, and not have 6 in a row?

Tags: pokemon-go

I used to go into the gym and it would show six Pokemon who would fight in a row, and when one died the next one would start immediately. Now I can only have one in battle at a time. How can I change this?

Comment: Are you trying to attack a friendly gym? In friendly gyms, you can only use 1 Pokémon, whereas in other teams gyms, you can use 6.

Comment: I understand now. I was mystic and he was valor. That's why. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The gym you're "attacking" is controlled by your team - you're training it.

When powering up friendly gyms, you are limited to one pokemon.

Update: As of 0.41.x, powering up friendly gyms are now 6v6.

Comment: When I was fighting there was only one, but my friend who was with me could fight and as the Pokemon died the next one automatically popped up to fight

Comment: is your friend on the same team as you?

Comment: @Susan Then your friend is on a different team. If your team controls it you can use only 1 Pokemon to train. If it is an enemy team then you can use 6 Pokemon to attack it.

Answer (score 4):

As of the [latest update](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-101016/) (12th of October) you can use 6 Pokemon while training a gym.

> Updated Gym Training: Trainers can now bring six Pokémon to battle at friendly Gyms. The CP of the Pokémon you are battling may be temporarily adjusted lower for your training session.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as these guys have mentioned already. Attacking friendly gyms is called "training". You can only use 1 pokemon in the gym battle, but in the end, the pokemon you used will still have 1 hp if you lose.

Attacking a rival gym allows you to have 6 pokemon with you.

Think of it like this. Friendly=duel (1v1), and Rival=war (6v6)

Comment: More like friendly is solo running a gauntlet.